# Neo4j config-migrator utility failure

Tags: neo4j, migration

I'm trying to migrate a Neo4j DB from 2.3.9 to 3.1.1.

The DB migration itself worked fine by stopping the 2.x version, setting allow_store_upgrade=true in the neo4j.properties and dbms.allow_format_migration=true in the configuration file conf/neo4j.conf.

To ensure that the config files are correctly migrated into one neo4j.conf file as well I tried to use the config-migrator utility. I followed the upgrade guide https://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/

But while trying this I ran into a problem.

I can't figure out which neo4j pathes to use within the config-migrator utility command line:

```
java -jar config-migrator.jar path/to/neo4j2.3 path/to/neo4j3.0
```

I tried different approaches to point to the "old" and "new" Neo4j data but nothing worked. The migration utility always returns the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid   Neo4j 2.3 directory 'my different path trials': missing conf subdirectory
at org.neo4j.config.ConfigMigrator.validateSrcPath(ConfigMigrator.java:787)
at org.neo4j.config.ConfigMigrator.<init>(ConfigMigrator.java:159)
at org.neo4j.config.ConfigMigrator.main(ConfigMigrator.java:134)
```

I can't figure out what's the right path to point to the 'conf subdirectory'.

Any help or hint how to migrate the conf files from Neo4j 2.x into 3.x is greatly appreciated.

Krid

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to execute the migration utility on OSX:

- Just create a /conf subdirectory within the neo4j data directory and
  copy the conf files into this directory.
- Execute the migration tool on the parent directory

Krid